# Redirect user if token has expired and api call gives 401 in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, authentication, redirect, refactoring

I was wondering if their is a proper way to refactor a code where I a checking if token is expired or not based on api resposen code `401`. but how can I use a single code in the entire app, even with the `navigator` functionality with it.

current code:

```
if(error.code == 401){
 _prefs.remove("token");
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.id);
}
```

now if I have 10 api call code on single screen, I need to keep doing this for every `function` / `method`. how to refactor is code style ?

Comment: you can do that by learning and implementing flutter bloc in your project you can learn it here https://bloclibrary.dev/#/

Comment: you can use http_interceptor, please reference this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579974/how-to-integrate-http-interceptor-for-flutter-for-retrying-requests , it has full code , you can directly test it.

Comment: I am using provider already. can any thing be done with it ? also I am managing the `http code` so that is good. but how to trigger redirect based on the class without `build context` is my question. even provider will require one.